# Irrelevant search results with lucene.net

Tags: c#, full-text-search, lucene.net

I have been developing a search engine for a business directory application using Lucene.net. However when i search for **Sports shop** it returns the result of other shops including the sports shops because the key word **shop** matches with that. So how can i prioritize that it should return the results which is matches with the keyword **sport**

If anyone have solution for this please share here. Any helpful example or links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would very much appreciate it if you could paste some code to give you a better example.

However, from reading your question I think that what you need is a phrase query to give Sports Shop a higher boost.

My implementation of this query is this:

public List QueryToPhraseQuery(string pQuery) {

```
QueryParsers.Classic.MultiFieldQueryParser oPhraseParser = new QueryParsers.Classic.MultiFieldQueryParser(Version, FieldArray, Analyzer, BoostDictionary);
List<PhraseQuery> lstPhraseQuery = new List<PhraseQuery>();
HashSet<Term> lstTerms = new HashSet<Term>();
oPhraseParser.Parse(pQuery).ExtractTerms(lstTerms);


foreach (var group in lstTerms.GroupBy(x => x.Field))
{
    PhraseQuery oPhraseQuery = new PhraseQuery() { Boost = 10, Slop = 3 };
    foreach (var oTerm in group.ToList())
    {
        oPhraseQuery.Add(oTerm);
        if (oTerm.Field == Field.ImportantField)
            oPhraseQuery.Boost = 30;
    }
    lstPhraseQuery.Add(oPhraseQuery);
}

return lstPhraseQuery;
```

}

This would search for thing like this in your index which will match exactly and will return better results with more relevance

`attributedescriptions:"something something"~3^10.0 attributemajor:"something something"~3^30.0 description:"something something"~3^10.0 edescription:"something something"~3^10.0`

If you want me to give you an example using your code, just past eit and I can modify it to better fit your exam